# How can I see why a file is listed in "syntax error files" in vivado

Tags: syntax-error, hdl, vivado

Syntax error files:

[image]

I want to know where I can see the exact error info.There's no hint in vivado.
Thanks!

Comment: When you open the file, there should be a red square denoting the position of the error. Anyhow, your Vivado looks a bit older. Some older versions are not good in finding and displaying error. Some versions show wrong errors. You'll find all errors in the messages window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can usually check the message tab at the bottom of the screen. Anyhow Vivado is not particularly good at telling you what's wrong with your code (I'm not sure if this has to do with Vivado or parsing HDL in general), so be aware that your error may be "cascading" from an error above in your code than where the message indicates there's something wrong).

For instance, when making the following mistake in line 13:

```
13    reg [15:0] test_reg_0
14    reg [15:0] test_reg_1;
```

it will tell you test_reg_1 is not declared and mark it as an error everywhere it's referenced.